# Is it possible to evaluate an expression in launchd's ProgramArguments array?

Tags: macos, launchd

Is it possible to compose my [`launchd.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) file so that an embedded expression is evaluated and not treated as a literal value? And, if so, how?

I have a `~/Library/LaunchAgents/setenv.JAVA_HOME.plist` file which contains a `/bin/launchctl` call as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>setenv.JAVA_HOME</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
        <string>setenv</string>
        <string>JAVA_HOME</string>
        <string>$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Problem is, the `$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)` expression is not evaluated and instead the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is assigned the literal value `$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)`.

I asked this question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042253) last week but have had so few views I'm guessing that that's not the place for it.

Comment: So, you're in essence trying to find a way to set a global environment variable, no? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64916/

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer in the original Stack Overflow question, [Is it possible to evaluate an expression in launchd's ProgramArguments array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35136985/1071320)

It is possible by means of this bash command:

```
/bin/bash -c '/bin/launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)'
```

The plist file you want is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test.so</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/bin/launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: klanomath, what is the value of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable on your machine after the above file is loaded on login? i.e. what gets printed in Terminal when you run this command: `launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is better suited as a comment it's much to long so I made it an answer:

Specs:

- OS X 10.10.5
- JDKs 1.8.0_72 **and** 1.7.0_80 installed (for testing purposes)

Using two different plists *test.so.global* installed to /Library/LaunchDaemons with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test.so.global</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/bin/launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and  *test.so.user* installed to ~/Library/LaunchAgents with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test.so.user</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/bin/launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and both loaded I get the following results:

```
host:~ user$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home
host:~ user$ launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home
host:~ user$ sudo launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Only loading *test.so.global* yields:

```
host:~ user$ echo $JAVA_HOME
    #empty line
host:~ user$ launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME
host:~ user$ sudo launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Only loading *test.so.user* yields:

```
host:~ user$ echo $JAVA_HOME
    #empty line
host:~ user$ launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home
host:~ user$ sudo launchctl getenv JAVA_HOME
```

So depending on how/where you want to set JAVA_HOME use either both or one of the two plists.